# pkgdown action failing at build XML

Tags: r, xml, github-actions, pkgdown

```
✖ Failed to build XML 3.99-0.3
  
  Error: Error: <callr_remote_error: Failed to build source package 'XML'>
```

Has anyone else experienced this error in the pkgdown github action?
Looks like a bug in building the XML package itself, not sure if there's anything I can do about it.

In the github action output looks errors like this occur. They looks specific to internal functions in XML.

```
OE> DocParse.c: In function ‘RS_XML_ParseTree’:
  OE> DocParse.c:165:7: error: ‘PROBLEM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  OE>   165 |       PROBLEM "Can't find file %s", CHAR_DEREF(STRING_ELT(fileName, 0))
  OE>       |       ^~~~~~~
  OE> DocParse.c:165:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  OE> DocParse.c:165:14: error: expected ‘;’ before string constant
  OE>   165 |       PROBLEM "Can't find file %s", CHAR_DEREF(STRING_ELT(fileName, 0))
  OE>       |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  OE>       |              ;
  OE> DocParse.c:229:14: error: expected ‘;’ before string constant
  OE>   229 |       PROBLEM "error in creating parser for %s", name
  OE>       |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  OE>       |              ;
```

Comment: "Has anyone else experienced this error in [...] github action?" - Yes, exactly this one. Did you find a solution? Did you report this upstream anywhere?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/r-lib/actions/issues/559

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be fixed, see this issue for more details: https://github.com/r-lib/actions/issues/559.

You can add `pak-version: devel` in the Github Actions. Here's an example:

```yaml
- uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
  with:
    extra-packages: any::pkgdown, local::.
    needs: website
    pak-version: devel # See https://github.com/r-lib/actions/issues/559
```

Comment: `pak-version: rc` might be enough by now.

Comment: And actually, it is not required at all any longer: https://github.com/r-lib/actions/issues/559#issuecomment-1383684440